# CiviCase - remember user choices in search filters for activities

Tags: wordpress, civicase

We are using CiviCRM 5.5.3 and CiviCase on Wordpress 4.9.8

Similar to "make activity filter user preference an optional setting" [CRM-20799](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20799)
we wish to make the system remember user choices in case activity tab.
Currently all filters are remove with every refresh.

Alternatively we would be happy if we could set the field Status to "Scheduled" by default.

Any way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

The setting `Preserve activity filters as a user preference` present in Display Preferences is limited to only Activity tab displayed on the contact summary page. As of now, there is no way to save the user choices in case activity tab.

Similarly, to select `Scheduled` as a default option for status, you might need to write a minor customization in an extension to make it work. Either using the `buildForm` hook and [setting default value](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/#example) OR using a smal js code snippet.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for the hint using `buildform`. Will be looking into it.